# antivirus check on PHP image upload necessary or not?

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, security, upload

Is it necessary to scan images uploaded by users through a html form with PHP?

Are the following security measures sufficient:

- file is checked for MIME/getimagesize()
- the original filename is not used
- the image is resized - the original is not stored
- htaccess forbids execution of anything that is not JPEG / PNG

Is it necessary to scan the file from the user with antivirus? How can I do that possibly with PHP?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: how paranoid do you feel? if you resize the image- you are basically creating a brand new one, nothing of the originally is really left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why using an antivirus could be useful:**

It is technically possible for an image to exploit a vulnerability in a system, not just as metadata, but in different ways, depending on the software that opens the image.

For instance, one of the first PSP vulnerabilities was due to the way the image viewer parsed a TIFF image (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-downgrade-your-psp-and-upgrade-to-a-custom-firmware-part-one/#2.00).

Although *probably* unlikely, there could be a bug/vulnerability/backdoor in the library that resizes the image, so if you want to go the extremely cautious route, the order would be:

1. Hand the image to the antivirus
2. Process/store the image in any way.

You may use a library that offers PHP - antivirus integration, such as: http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-clamav/ (but keep in mind that DoS might also occur if requests queue up for a long time, when handing files to the AV; security often involves trade offs!).

NB: Having your library packages kept up to date goes a longer way than an AV, since after modification of the original image, any vulnerability exploitation will be probably corrupted/lost.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to antivirus scan images. Although you can technically put a virus into the image data, it is not gonna get executed as code anywhere. What you can do is strip meta-data to make sure that it is not used to exploit any bugs that exists in image viewers.

Depending on what program you use to process the image there is possibly options to remove meta-tags in your conversions.

I personally use pngcrush or pngquant (for retina images) for images I put on the web. If you use imagemagick you can use the "-strip" option.

Comment: <personal_opinion> I would not involve a virus scanner here as it is most likely ever gonna give you problems with false positives and never find an actual threat. </personal_opinion>